# Как убрать дергание у sticky блока, которому при скроле к нему задается position: fixed и убирается при скроле от него

Tags: javascript, sticky

Когда свойство top блока, к которому происходит скрол становится **меньше** чем высота хедера, ему добавляется класс .sticky, которые добавляет этому блоку свойство position: fixed.
Когда свойство top sticky блока становится **больше** высоты хедера, у него убирается класс .sticky и он снова находится в обычном потоке документа.

У меня небольшой опыт работы с JS поэтому завис, перепробовав разные варианты.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Мой код:

```js
stickyFilterList();

function stickyFilterList() {
      const filterListWrap = document.querySelector('.filter-wrapper');
      const headerHeight = document.querySelector('.header').getBoundingClientRect().height;

      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleWindowScorll);

      function handleWindowScorll() {
        const coords = filterListWrap.getBoundingClientRect();
        const filterListWrapTopPos = coords.top;

        if (filterListWrapTopPos < headerHeight) {
          filterListWrap.classList.add('sticky');
          console.log('position: fixed');
        } else {
          filterListWrap.classList.remove('sticky');
          console.log('position: absolute');
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
.header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 120px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

.portfolio-hero {
    height: 1053px;
    margin-bottom: 124px;
    background: yellow;
}

.brands {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    min-height: 4000px;
    background: orange;
}

.filter-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: -57px;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 462px;
    width: 120px;
    background: pink;
}

.filter-wrapper.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 120px;
  }

footer {
  height: 600px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
   
</header>

<section class="portfolio-hero">

</section>

<section class="brands">
  <div class="filter-wrapper">
      
   </div>
</section>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, это все можно сделать и без JS:

```css
.header {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    height: 120px;
    background: grey;
}

.portfolio-hero {
    height: 1053px;
    margin-bottom: 124px;
    background: yellow;
}

.brands {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background: orange;
}

.filter-wrapper {
    position: sticky;
    top: 120px;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 462px;
    margin-bottom: -400px;
    width: 120px;
    background: pink;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<section class="portfolio-hero"></section>
<div class="filter-wrapper">text</div>
<section class="brands"></section>
```

Comment: Благодарю вас за интересное решение. 
А возможно ли с помощью css сделать еще чтобы filter-wrapper не наезжал на футер, а останавливался внизу блока brands??

Я добавил футер в html

Comment: Можно. Почитайте про `position: sticky;` и сможете сделать так как вам надо.